# Why is Pandas read CSV getting different row count on different computers?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a situation in which Pandas read_csv is reading a different row count on different computers.  **Yet, I have verified the very same script and same input file are being used.**

here is the script:

```
import pandas as pd 
import csv
PACEpath=r"e:\LMT\PACE_Export.csv"
PACEDF = pd.read_csv(PACEpath, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,
                     error_bad_lines=True,
                     usecols=["LOCATION_CODE", "PACE_NUMBER"])
print "PACEDF rows: ", PACEDF.shape[0]
```

Here is the problem:
Computer #S reads 123,889 rows into the dataframe
Computer #B reads 123,889 rows into the dataframe
Computer #M1 reads 102,345 rows into the dataframe
Computer #M2 reads 102,345 rows into the dataframe

I checked various versions and I see this:
Computer #S conda=4.3.8 requests=2.12.4 pandas= 0.19.2 CPython=3.6.0 Windows=7
Computer #B conda=4.3.8 requests=2.12.4 pandas= 0.19.2 CPython=2.7.13 Windows=7
Computer #M1 conda=4.3.24 requests=2.12.4 pandas= 0.20.1 CPython=2.7.13 Windows=7
Computer #M2 conda=4.3.8 requests=2.12.4 pandas= 0.19.2 CPython=3.6.0 Windows=7

I have tried excluding the parameters in the read_csv such as:

```
pd.read_csv(PACEpath, usecols=["LOCATION_CODE", "PACE_NUMBER"])
```

same results.  Please help.

Comment: Did you verify hash of files? You can try the following: `import hashlib; filepath = r"e:\LMT\PACE_Export.csv"; print hashlib.md5(open(filepath, 'rb').read()).hexdigest()` and check if the file outputs same hash or not.

Comment: Cedric, I followed your suggestion and hashed the file on two different computers and both came up with the exact same hex output string.  In fact, in the test I'm doing, I have both computers going to the same file on a shared network drive, so I know it is the very same file.

Comment: is it possible for you to share the file?

Comment: Perhaps you could investigate by cutting the files down in size by half each time until you get the same result and then try and spot which lines cause different results.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share the exact file due to proprietary info inside.  But, I have looked at the last row that is read successfully and the following row and I don't 'see' anything unusual.  I did execute 'conda update --all' on both computers exhibiting the problem and that solved the issue on one, but not the other.  So now I am down to one computer (M2) that doesn't read all rows in the CSV.  Based on Martin's suggestion, I have started looking at other CSVs and resizing to find the break point.